# Build warning, C4067, Should I even be concerned about warning?

Tags: c++

I was given a header file and I have to provide the implementation. I originally changed the FLOAT_ARRAY_H TO FLOAT_ARRAY_HPP. I also added comments after the directive which I have also deleted.

```
#ifndef FLOAT ARRAY_H
#define FLOAT ARRAY_H
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
```

If I need to combine all the files into one to post I will

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org). Also, please include the exact error messages in your post.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4067?view=msvc-160 I googled the compiler warning you got, and got this page with a pretty clear description of what the warning indicates and what you can do about it.

Comment: Building with what? VS Code? Explain how you build and quote the exact error message. **edit** nvm, it was just a typo, closure incoming hopefully :-P

Comment: Thank you both next time I will include the entire file, I read that page and that is why I moved the comments from after the pre-processor directive.

Comment: Please also read [`"Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) -- especially in a header file.

Comment: Also next time post the exact text of the warning. If this is Visual Studio Community/ Professional or Enterprise the text can be found in the Output Tab in a better format than the errors list.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry took me posting it to see that I was missing the space between FLOAT and ARRAY!

```
#ifndef FLOAT_ARRAY_H
#define FLOAT_ARRAY_H
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Did that solve the issue?

Comment: I read that you should never delete questions.  Yes it did, I was confused by not having comments after the directives because they have never caused an issue before.  The teacher uses camel case but I prefer to use the _ which is why I messed up.